# Yii code issue: Works on local machine fails on server

Tags: php, yii

I have been encountering some strange behaviour with some bits of my yii code.Let me pick out one in particular.

The code

```
$model = new Socialdemo;
$model = $model->findByAttributes(array('fk_recordid'=>$record_id));

$new = new Socialdemo();
$data = $model->attributes;
$data['fk_recordid'] = $new_recordid;
unset($data['id']); //unset id since we want to insert
$new->setAttributes($data, false);
$new->save();
```

On my local development machine is works just fine but when I deploy it on the server if brings up an error on the line of code

```
$data = $model->attributes;
```

It brings out the php error

> Trying to get property of non-object

What am I missing?

Comment: Is that all the code you have? Because at least your code doesn't define the $model variable, so it's pretty hard to tell what's the problem if there is more code somewhere.

Comment: @Rinuwise I have edited and added the code that defines the model variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the same Db data on server?
have you checked on NULL value?

`$model = $model->findByAttributes(array('fk_recordid'=>$record_id));`

Comment: Thanks it led me to the solution

Comment: variable, foreign key of this model

Answer (score 0):

Why are you missing the brackets after the new declaration

```
$model = new Socialdemo();
```

Also, I assume you are including a file to the Socialdemo class, is the file copied to the correct location and path correct on the server?